# Batch files by winrar

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I want to archive files in a folder by winrar.

I only can archive one file using `rar a -p0000 C:\backup\ C:\backup\test.txt`

How can I archive files in a folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try:

```
rar a -p0000 C:\backup\ C:\backup\*
```

If `rar.exe` does not accept that then (firstly its crap, and you should GET RID OF IT) and secondly you can use:

```
pushd "C:\backup\"
for /r %%a in (*) do (
rar a -p0000 C:\backup\ C:\backup\%%a
)
popd
```

And that should work just as fine. If thats not what your looking for or that doesn't work, please say so.

Mona

Comment: Thanks. I use `rar a -p0000 C:\backup\ C:\backup\*` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

RAR syntax:

```
RAR <command>  [ -<switches> ]  <archive>  [ <@listfiles...> ] [<files...> ]  [ <path_to_extract\> ]
```

I can't identify `<archive>` in your command line. Wouldn't it be:

```
rar a -p0000 C:\backup.rar "drive:\some folder\*.*"
```